# I want to convert JSON data to an array

Tags: php, json, laravel

JSON data is as follows:

```
0: {
   'row': 0,
   'col': 0,
   'value': 4.5
},
1: {
   'row': 0,
   'col': 1,
   'value': 4.3
},
2: {
   'row': 0,
   'col': 2,
   'value': 4.9
}
```

I want to create an array `data` like `data[r][c] = value`.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: `json_decode()`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Can I get an array like data[row][col] using json_decode?
For example, data[3][5] should return a value with row=3, col=5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your JSON data is invalid. Make sure you have a valid json string. You can use tools like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON data. From there, you can parse using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), and then build whatever array structure you want. For example,

```
//valid JSON
$json = '[{"row":0,"col":0,"value":4.5},{"row":0,"col":1,"value":4.3},{"row":0,"col":2,"value":4.9},{"row":1,"col":1,"value":3.1}]';

//parse json data
$data = json_decode( $json );

//a new array to hold the parsed data
$parsed = [];

//iterate over the json data and re-structure as desired
foreach( $data as $item ) {

    //do we have a place for this row yet?
    if( ! isset($parsed[$item->row]) ) {
        //no array for this row, create an empty one
        $parsed[ $item->row ] = [];
    }

    //set the value for this column
    $parsed[ $item->row ][ $item->col ] = $item->value;

}
```

The output of `$parsed` would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4.5
            [1] => 4.3
            [2] => 4.9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 3.1
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way to solve it with a simple statement?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Your asking for something nested from a flat structure. No magic method for that.